# php inserting object into sessions

Tags: php, session, object

is it possible to insert an object into a session instead of creating a different sessions (in PHP)???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['myObj'] = $myObj;
```

(Where `$myObj` is an object)